# Mongo's elemMatch with meteor publish composite

Tags: meteor, mongodb-query, meteorite

I have a Mongo collection that looks similar to the below example, I am using meteor-publish-composite, https://atmospherejs.com/reywood/publish-composite to publish documents to the client. I know with Mongo I can do the following to return specific items within the authors array.

```
db.books.find({"authors.authorSlug": "author-1}, {authors: {$elemMatch: { authorSlug: "author-1"}});
```

When I try to achieve the same thing using meteor-publish-composite, this does not seem to work as it returns the entire the authors' array, my code is as below.

`Books.find({"authors.authorSlug": slug}, {authors: {$elemMatch:{authorSlug: slug}}})`;

Is this even possible to achieve with publish-composite?

```
{
    "title" : "Book1",
    "authors" : [
        {
            "name" : "Author 1",
            "authorSlug": "author-1"
        },
        {
            "name" : "Author 2",
            "slug" : "author-2"
        },
    ],
    "slug" : "book1"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You only use publish-composite when you are trying to join 2 or more related collections into a single reactive subscription. You simply need a standard publish/subscribe for your collection - and you say you have working code so I don't see what your problem is! Or are you trying to get at your books data in addition to other data around it?